# What's a good mnemonic for intensive and extensive properties?

Tags: mnemonic

For some reason, I have always had a hard time remembering which is which. Intensive properties don't depend on the amount. Extensive do. What's a good mnemonic to help remember this?

Comment: I've never heard one... but I can try to make one up. "Intensive is within (or inside?)"? Or maybe "Extensive depends on the extent"? Or "Intensive is in the mass"? Or... yeah, those are the best I can come up with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about efficient memorization methods rather than physics.

Comment: Which page would this question go on then?

Comment: @Danu I don't see any difference from this question to any other question asking about intuitive explanations or logical descriptions of phenomena. I find this on-topic.

Comment: @Steeven The difference here is that this question explicitly asks for a mnemonic. However, you are of course entitled to disagree with me :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually remember it by telling myself that

- some **EX**tra amount is needed to increase an **EX**tensive property.

Extensive properties are *mass*, *volume*, *heat capacity* etc. which all increase with more substance.

If a property is not extensive then it is intensive. Like temperature, which does not increase with more substance.

Comment: I think if you have learned enough, then you would remember the quantities that have a specific ahead of them. So for me, I just look for whether or not specific of that quantity exist or not. Like specific volume exists but not specific temperature.

Comment: @YoungKindaichi I've never heard about *specific mass*, though.

Comment: Yes! That's useless to define. :)